# Concatenate list elements into a number in Mathematica

Tags: list, wolfram-mathematica, concatenation

I am trying to generate circular prime numbers in Mathematica 8.
A circular prime number is a number such that all rotations of its digits are prime

Eg. 197 is circular because 971, and 719, are primal too.

Now, in order to test if a prime number is circular, I generate all rotations. I do this as follows:

```
p = IntegerDigits[197];
Table[RotateLeft[p, n], {n, Length[p]}]
```

Which consequently returns

```
{{9, 7, 1}, {7, 1, 9}, {1, 9, 7}}
```

However this is where I get stuck. What I would like to do now is to grab the elements of each inner list and concatenate them together in a sequential order so that the output becomes this

```
{971, 719, 197}
```

So that I can test if all rotations satisfy PrimeQ[].

While I on the one hand could have this done by looping through the list, it seems to me as if there is a better way that I am just not realizing.

Comment: `NestList` could be used as an alternative to `Table` in the first part. You are probably well aware of this.  `NestList[RotateLeft,p,(Length@p)-1]`

Comment: I was in fact unaware of this! I have only been using Mathematica for a few weeks and I am constantly learning! Thank you very much, TomD, I am sure `NestList` shall come in handy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`FromDigits` is what you're looking for.

```
FromDigits /@ {{9, 7, 1}, {7, 1, 9}, {1, 9, 7}}
{971, 719, 197}
```